# Elegant code when there are many subclasses?

Tags: java, enums, subclass

I have an interesting programming problem that has had me stumped for days. Some context to aid my questions:

Currently I am writing a game that uses a Material Emum to hold all the materials needed in the game ie Material.DIRT, Material.WATER, Material.CLOTH ...

However I wish to make the code as modifiable as possible and have the ability that should someone want to extend the game to add new materials they can do so. Thus my current Enum system breaks down and so I have attempted to switch to a Class/Subclass system. I have found two ways to do this, they are explained below with their pros and cons.

Case 1 - Having an abstract Material class and subclassing.
Thus every material would extend Material. This is advantageous as we can now "group" like materials together ie Fabric could extend Material and then Wool and Cotton etc extend this. The problem with this is that for every material there has to exist a class and with so little parameters for each material it feels like a waste. If there is 1000 materials there would be 1000 classes all with virtually nothing in them. I could cut this down by having anonymous classes but now the code has no way to differentiate one material from the other. I could use an id system which is the major problem with case 2.

The question for case 1 is:
Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Case 2 - Having a single Material class and instantiating each new material as an instance of this class defining each material with a different id/name. This saves a lot of writing and also allows us to differentiate between materials. The problem with this is now we have an id system, what do we base this system on? Strings, ints? I ask this because I am always keen to have a complex free system that avoids using hardcoded strings and ints in the code. This is why I like the enums as there is no worry of typesetting. Another problem is users wanting to add new materials could have conflicting ids with other users.

My question for case 2 is: 
Is there a full proof method of being able to differentiate instances uniquely and consistently (is the same every runtime)?

Thank you for reading. Any help or methods on how best to do this would be most appreciated.

Edit: I should note that some materials may have methods and behaviours associated with them. Some behaviours may be unique to certain materials and some that are similar for a "group".

Comment: Have an `interface Material` requires you return, say, `String materialName()`. The `interface` can also require returning various behaviours of the `Material` - `getStrength()` etc. Then have your `enum` implement that `interface` for your internal materials. Others can provide their own implementations if desired.

Comment: I went with Case 1 for my own project (elements and combination children of multiple elements, for an elemental RPG setting). I tried enums and various other methods (interfaces, etc) but none worked well. An alternative approach is what Elazar says, below.

Comment: Further to your edit I would suggest using a Visitor Pattern to access the properties of your material - this way you don't have to expose behaviour directly and you can leverage polymorphism to switch behaviour. This would require you go with `CASE 1` and hide everything behind an `interface`. With the Visitor Pattern you would not have to _distinguish_ between materials so do not need an ID and you can use anonymous classes as long as they override the relevant `accept` methods to change their behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I feel this interface method combined with using a Visitor Pattern is the best way to do and has worked very well for this project. I would say this would be my preferred accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a configuration file with all the materials in it, written in some DSL (simple table, basically).

Comment: I think that different materials might have different _behaviours_ which is where polymorphism comes in. If that's the case then this solution would be tricky to implement (Drules?).

Comment: It depend on the implementation, but I believe that the behaviours for simple things such as materials in a game can be easily encoded in a table.

Comment: Agreed, and you get my +1. But if the OP wants some sort of Visitor Pattern (which would make sense - say if an item of clothing is built of several materials and it gets cut or some such) then this becomes troublesome.

Comment: You have a point. I would say my answer is more like a third case to consider.